# C# - A* algorithm gives wrong results

Tags: c#, algorithm, a-star

I am trying to make 4-directional A-star pathfinding algorithm in C# but can't make it work properly. In Main method i have a example 5x5 *int* array map to set which fields can be accessed and which not (0 - clear field, 1 - obstacle). As example i set *START* point at (1, 3) and *TARGET* point at (4, 4), so i would expect path to avoid wall and proceed etc. but it doesn't. I've even made my algorithm display every parent and it's successors (neighbour). In my case it displays (2,4) as one of the nodes despite being marked as obstacle in Fields (Map), how did it happen? There is clear statement in *GetSuccessors* method to include only the ones marked as 0 but it still includes (2, 4) point. I am not really sure if something is wrong with *GetSuccessors* or *FindPath* (main algorithm).

Example map:

```
int[,] fields = new int[5, 5] //MAP, 1 - OBSTACLE
        {
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }
        };
```

Example points:

```
Node start = new Node(1, 3); //START LOCATION ON MAP
Node target = new Node(4, 4); //TARGET LOCATION ON MAP
```

Produced path (from TARGET to START):

```
4, 4
3, 4
2, 4
1, 3
```

Full code (FindPath and GetSuccessors are the main ones but i still could make something wrong with other methods):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FoxLib
{
    public class Node
    {
        public Node(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public int x, y; //POSITION ON MAP
        public Node parent; //NEEDED TO RETRIEVE PATH LATER
        public int G, H, F; 
        //G - COST FROM START NODE TO THIS NODE
        //H - COST FROM THIS NODE TO TARGET (HEURISTIC)
        //F - G + H; NODE COST
    }

    public class Pathfinding
    {
        public static void FindPath(int startX, int startY, int targetX, int targetY, int[,] fields) //MAIN ALGORITHM
        {
            bool pathFound=false; //IS PATH AVAILABLE?
            Node start = new Node(startX, startY); //STARTING NODE
            Node target = new Node(targetX, targetY); //TARGET NODE
            start.parent = start;
            start.G = 0;
            start.H = Math.Abs(target.x - start.x) + Math.Abs(target.y - start.y);
            start.F = start.G + start.H;
            Node current = new Node(0, 0);
            List<Node> openList = new List<Node>(); //NODES WAITING TO BE CHECKED
            List<Node> closedList = new List<Node>(); //ALREADY CHECKED NODES
            openList.Add(start);

            while(openList.Count>0) //DO AS LONG AS THERE ARE STILL NODES TO DISCOVER
            {
                current = MinFNode(openList); //FIND NODE WITH LOWEST F COST (LOWER=BETTER PATH)
                openList.Remove(current); //REMOVE CURRENT NODE FROM QUEUE

                if ((current.x==target.x)&&(current.y==target.y)) //TARGET FOUND
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("PATH FOUND");
                    pathFound = true;
                    //DISPLAY PATH (FROM TARGET TO START) BY CHECKING PARENTS
                    Console.WriteLine("[FULL PATH]");
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(current.x + ", " + current.y);
                        current = current.parent;
                    } while ((current.x != start.x) && (current.y != start.y));
                    Console.WriteLine(start.x + ", " + start.y);
                    break;
                }

                List<Node> successors = GetSuccessors(current.x, current.y, fields); //GET SUCCESSORS
                foreach (Node node in successors)
                { 
                    node.parent = current; //SET CURRENT NODE AS PARENT TO RETRIEVE PATH LATER
                    node.G = current.G + 10; //10 - DISTANCE FROM CURRENT TO ITS SUCCESSOR, current.G DISTANCE FROM CURRENT TO START
                    node.H = Math.Abs(target.x - node.x) + Math.Abs(target.y - node.y); //HEURISTIC DISTANCE TO TARGET
                    node.F = node.G + node.H; //NODE FINAL COST

                    Console.WriteLine(current.x + ", " + current.y + " PARENT | SUCCESSOR: " + node.x + ", " + node.y);  //TEST DISPLAY TO CHECK SUCCESSORS CURRENT NODE PRODUCED

                    if (closedList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.x == node.x && l.y == node.y) != null) //IF SUCCESSOR ALREADY EXISTS ON CLOSED LIST
                    {
                        Node temp = closedList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.x == node.x && l.y == node.y);
                        if (node.F < temp.F) //IF NEW PATH TO THIS NODE IS BETTER? (LOWER F = SHORTER PATH)
                        {
                            closedList.Remove(temp); //REMOVE OLD NODE
                            temp.parent = node.parent;
                            temp.F = node.F;
                            closedList.Add(temp); //ADD UPDATED NODE
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    if(openList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.x == node.x && l.y == node.y) != null) //IF SUCCESSOR ALREADY EXISTS ON OPEN LIST
                    {
                        Node temp = openList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.x == node.x && l.y == node.y);
                        if (node.F < temp.F) //IF NEW PATH TO THIS NODE IS BETTER? (LOWER F = SHORTER PATH)
                        {
                            openList.Remove(temp); //REMOVE OLD NODE
                            temp.parent = node.parent;
                            temp.F = node.F;
                            openList.Add(temp); //ADD UPDATED NODE
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        openList.Add(node); //ADD SUCCESSOR TO OPEN LIST
                    }
                }
                closedList.Add(current); //MARK CURRENT NODE AS CHECKED (NO NEED TO CHECK IT UNTIL BETTER PATH TO THIS NODE IS FOUND)
            }
            if(!pathFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PATH NOT FOUND");
            }
        }

        //FIND NODE WITH LOWEST F COST
        public static Node MinFNode(List<Node> nodes)
        {
            Node result = nodes[0];
            foreach(Node node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.F < result.F)
                    result = node;
            }
            return result;
        }

        //GET SUCCESSORS OF CURRENT NODE (ONLY THE ONES WITH "0" VALUE)
        public static List<Node> GetSuccessors(int x, int y, int[,] fields) 
        {
            List<Node> Successors = new List<Node>();
            if ((x - 1 >= 0) && (fields[x - 1, y]==0))
                Successors.Add(new Node(x - 1, y)); //LEFT

            if ((x + 1 < fields.GetLength(0)) && (fields[x + 1, y]==0))
                Successors.Add(new Node(x + 1, y)); //RIGHT

            if ((y - 1 >= 0) && (fields[x, y - 1]==0))
                Successors.Add(new Node(x, y - 1)); //UP

            if ((y + 1 < fields.GetLength(1)) && (fields[x, y + 1]==0))
                Successors.Add(new Node(x, y + 1)); //DOWN

            return Successors; //RETURN LIST OF AVAILABLE SUCCESSORS
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            int[,] fields = new int[5, 5] //MAP, 1 - OBSTACLE
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }
            };

            Node start = new Node(1, 3); //START LOCATION ON MAP
            Node target = new Node(4, 4); //TARGET LOCATION ON MAP

            FindPath(start.x,start.y,target.x,target.y,fields); //MAIN ALGORITHM

            Console.WriteLine("END");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Your question is "I wrote a program, it doesn't work, I don't know how to fix it".  This isn't a service for finding bugs in your programs.  Read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  apply those techniques, and come back when you have a *specific* question. Learn to debug today; it will be much more efficient than just watching your questions get closed on SO.

Comment: You can start by defining what is `x` and what is `y` in your code. Looks like you are considering addressing to be  (x, y). But in C# 2d arrays, indexing is `array[y, x]` where `0 <= y < array.GetLength(0)`, `0 <= x < array.GetLength(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ivan pointed out, you're working from a false assumption.  In a two-dimensional array the first index is the row number, not the column.  This means that `fields[2,4]` is second row, fourth column... which is 0.

Simple fix... switch the indexing on all your `fields` references to `fields[y, x]` and you should be a step closer.

Eric's comment was perfectly valid however.  You should have been able to pick this up with a little debugging.  Step through the code and see what is actually happening and you'll get a much better insight into the problem.  Since VS2015 Community Edition is free there's not much reason not to, and if you're not developing on Windows there are other C# IDEs that will allow you to step through your code and examine the state of the program as it operates.  MonoDevelop is the go-to on Linux and Mac.

Comment: You are right, thanks, such small mistake made so many problems. Actually the problem is not because of not using [y, x] format but mainly because testing array was declared in bad way. Of course using [y, x] format in algorithm would work, but i can just invert testing array. Anyway, problem only exists for testing array because my real input array (from outside of whole class) was made in [x, y] as well so it works good. I also managed to fix seconds error which caused bad path displayed but it was only display-related problem, path is calculated as it should, so problem is solved, thanks.